# Xcode Retrieve, Perform Function and Add Data to SQL DB

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode4.3

I think I'm making this more complicated than it has to be.  I have an Sqlite DB in my app.  I'm trying to pull the Lat/Long of each location, get the distance between the iPhone and the location and insert that distance back into the DB.  I would then be able to pull that data for my tableview and sort by distance.  Please let me know if I'm going about this the right way.

If this is the right way, I'm still drawing a blank on how to update one cell in each row of data.

Comment: Mate, what do you want do perform by your app? What does your app do?

Comment: I've currently pull my current location, determined the distance from each location in the DB from that current location, then populated that into a tableview.  I'm trying to sort that tableview from near to far away.  My thought was to append that distance to the array, resort that data and pull back into the tableview.